# Retrieve value of last key in dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key, key-value

I'm trying to extract financial figures from an API that returns a JSON object. The API does not explicitly state that the dictionaries returned are OrderedDicts however the output is always sorted thus I'm going to make the assumption that it is.

I need to retrieve the value of the last key in the dictionary as I need the most current financial figures. However I cannot explicitly use the name of the key to extract it as it is in a date format and may be different depending on the company using queried.

I tried to convert the dictionary object into a list and select the last key using an index of -1 however the conversion process seems to randomize the order of the dictionary no longer retrieves the last date.

So how would I go about retrieving the value of the last key in the dictionary?

Here is an example of what the JSON object looks like:

```
{'2007-06-01T00:00:00': 21.19,
 '2008-06-01T00:00:00': 26.01,
  '2009-06-01T00:00:00': 19.34,
  '2010-06-01T00:00:00': 22.88,
  '2011-06-01T00:00:00': 23.77,
  '2012-06-01T00:00:00': 14.77,
  '2013-06-01T00:00:00': 16.58,
  '2014-06-01T00:00:00': 14.02,
  '2015-06-01T00:00:00': 7.0,
  '2016-06-01T00:00:00': 9.08}
```

Comment: usually if the API doesn't specify that it does something it actually does, you shouldn't rely on it continuing to do that.

Comment: if the keys are all comparable then the highest would be the most recent so you do `max(data.keys())` to get the most recent key, depending on the format you might need to specify a `key=...` to put the dates into a format that will be correctly compared.

Comment: You could convert the date strings into actual `datetime` objects, sort them, and get the largest one.

Comment: You can't rely on API's behavior as it might change in the future. Just sort the dictionary by converting keys to `datetime` objects.

Comment: Even if the JSON returned by the API is ordered, once you run it through the JSON parser, it will no longer be ordered. You might be able to us [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to parse the keys into times then sort based on those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reconsidering the problem I realize that because the date is in a format that they are correctly comparable as strings, you can just do `k,v = max(data.items())` however if you (or someone else looking at this thread) uses a date format that doesn't work like that my original answer is below.

---

you can simply use the `max` builtin to compare the keys of the dictionary, to make sure they are all compared as dates and times you can use the `key` argument to compare them as datetime objects:

```
import datetime

data = {'2007-06-01T00:00:00': 21.19,
 '2008-06-01T00:00:00': 26.01,
  '2009-06-01T00:00:00': 19.34,
  '2010-06-01T00:00:00': 22.88,
  '2011-06-01T00:00:00': 23.77,
  '2012-06-01T00:00:00': 14.77,
  '2013-06-01T00:00:00': 16.58,
  '2014-06-01T00:00:00': 14.02,
  '2015-06-01T00:00:00': 7.0,
  '2016-06-01T00:00:00': 9.08}

def converter(timestamp):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

highest = max(data.keys(),key=converter)

print(highest) #2016-06-01T00:00:00
```

Comment: Actually `max(data.items(), key=...)` is more like it as OP wants to retrieve the value associated with the key. Make sure, `converter` takes a tuple instead of a timestamp.

Comment: Writing the converter function seemed simpler to only deal with the key then just get `value = data[highest]` but absolutely you could make it handle it that way too.

Comment: Makes sense. BTW, you don't need `.keys()`.

Comment: It is only three lines as an abstract for how the OP can go about solving their problem, lets not go too far into micro-optimizations.  I was going for clear and precise so I'd like to leave the answer as it is but should the OP (or anyone else) be interested in further optimizations/options then I imagine your comments will be useful to them.

Comment: Isn't a major point of that format from year down to seconds that you **don't** have to parse it but can just compare the strings? See [the first item here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles).

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think I noticed that right away but then wasn't sure so I got the more general solution instead.  Now that I think about it, yes just using `max(data.items())` would work fine with that format. silly me :)